# I can't open JS files in Windows from Filezilla

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ftp

I logged in to my FTP from Filezilla and tried to open a JS file, and it gave me the following error:

```
Script:    C:/.../slider.js
Line:      1
Char:      1
Error:     'document' is undefined
Code:      800A1391
Source:    Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

I have jQuery linked to the .php file as well...'document' comes from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Code is here...
});
```

I tried downloading the file and opening it, I tried removing the $(document).ready();, I tried removing jquery (which by the way, when I opened the jQuery file it gave me the same almost the same error). Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

One of the tags for this post was "asp.net", but to be honest I don't even know if it is related to asp.net...

Comment: What do you mean by "open a file"? In a browser? How are you running it? Are you attaching it to a web page?

Comment: right clicking and clicking "View/Edit". My default text editor is Notepad++...

Comment: And Notepad++ gives you the MS JScript runtime error? Or FileZilla gives you the error?

Comment: It's a window's error I think... If it's not then it would be Filezilla giving me the error...

Comment: The title of the error is "Windows Script Host"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by doing the following in Filezilla:

1. Go to Edit > Settings
2. Go to the 'File editing' section
3. Under 'Default Editor': Ensure that Notepad++ is selected as your custom editor
4. Change the radio button from 'Use filetype associations if available' to 'Always use default editor'

Comment: **1.** Under `Default Editor` (step 3 above), choose `Use custom editor` and browse to the location of Notepad++ (for me, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`). *(You must tell FileZilla where to find your custom editor's main exe file)* **2.** Now click the `Always use default editor` radio button. *The default editor is the custom editor you just selected.*

Comment: I was missing step #4

Answer (score 3):

You say that you're `right clicking and clicking "View/Edit"`, and it throws that error.

The error is occurring because Windows is executing the script, and the script has a problem (because it relies on another script being loaded).

So although you may be clicking "View/Edit", and expecting that this will open the file in Notepad++, what it is actually doing is assuming that "View" means "Run the script".

Clearly, Notepad++ is not the default action for this file type, or at least it isn't according to Filezilla. Maybe the default action isn't actually set the way you think it is, or maybe it's Filezilla that isn't respecting your default action.

The solutions:

- If Filezilla has an option "Open with..." that allows you to pick the program to open the file with, then use that and select Notepad++ manually. Even better, if it has the option to then make that the default, then tick it, and the problem should be solved permanently.
- Alternatively, just download the file to your local machine before trying to open it.

Comment: In the preferences of FileZilla, I made it so that Notepad++ opens everytime I click "View/Edit" so that I can edit it there...I did that with all file types. For an example, take the PHP file that calls the js file that isn't opening, right click on it and select "View/Edit" and then I can rdit it, it doesn't run...It opens up Notepad++. So I don't think that that is correct. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

I got this working in FileZilla by doing the following: -

1. Edit -> Settings
2. File editing -> Use custom editor [file path to notepad ++] *then*
3. |___File editing -> Filetype associations
4. Adding the line -> js "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
5. Click OK to save changes

This will stop windows script host from attempting to run the file and open in notepad++.

While the question has effectively been identified previously in the post I hope that someone finds this 'how-to' useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming problem. It's a file association problem - Windows is trying to execute your .js file instead of opening it in an Editor.

See this question on SuperUser: [running-javascript-files-js](https://superuser.com/questions/276614/running-javascript-files-js)

There's also some explanation of the error [here](http://www.highdots.com/forums/javascript/cant-open-js-file-w-260305.html).

Check your file associations again. Try restarting your machine. You will get more help if you ask this type of a question on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me after adding the file association.

- Edit -> Settings
- File Editing -> Select *Use filetype association if available* checkbox.
- Select Filetype Associations -> add association here
       **js "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"**
- OK
  *Note: change association according to your text editor application.*

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps. It is an easy one to do. Change the default file type for opening the js files.

1. Edit -> Settings
2. File editing -> Filetype associations
3. Adding the line -> js "C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

That's it. Finally, Click OK to save changes. 
It will work afterwards.